# How to get the a FeatureLayer full extent?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-flex-api, feature-layer, extents

Is there a way to get the extent of a FeatureLayer (with all its features, not only the ones on the map)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

featureLayer.layerDetails.extent

Answer (score 1):

what about

getGraphicsExtent(*yourFeatureLayer*.graphicProvider);

where getGraphicsExtent() method is in com.esri.ags.utils.GraphicUtil class.

Comment: getGraphicsExtent() maybe will return the extent of the graphics loaded on the map => that are in the graphicProvider.